# C# MVC 5 ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I created registration and login to my app. But when I login i don't see logged user. How can I do that? I create all redirection to home page when user is connected but I don't see connected user like on this site.

[image]

I was fallowing this tutorial. And all is working fine. But how can I get this?
On my site i have this:

[image]

My git. I didn't post any code, because is almost the same like in tutorial, except i added redirection to my home page.
https://github.com/ivanradunkovic/Vozila/tree/master/Vozila
Thanks

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>@ViewBag.Title - Vehicle</title>
    @Styles.Render("~/Content/css")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/modernizr")
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var appInsights=window.appInsights||function(config){
            function s(config){t[config]=function(){var i=arguments;t.queue.push(function(){t[config].apply(t,i)})}}var t={config:config},r=document,f=window,e="script",o=r.createElement(e),i,u;for(o.src=config.url||"//az416426.vo.msecnd.net/scripts/a/ai.0.js",r.getElementsByTagName(e)[0].parentNode.appendChild(o),t.cookie=r.cookie,t.queue=[],i=["Event","Exception","Metric","PageView","Trace"];i.length;)s("track"+i.pop());return config.disableExceptionTracking||(i="onerror",s("_"+i),u=f[i],f[i]=function(config,r,f,e,o){var s=u&&u(config,r,f,e,o);return s!==!0&&t["_"+i](config,r,f,e,o),s}),t
        }({
            instrumentationKey:"615aadc5-8508-46e7-aa93-713181a155ae"
        });

        window.appInsights=appInsights;
        appInsights.trackPageView();
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="navbar-header">
                <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                </button>
                @Html.ActionLink("Vehicle", "Index", "Home", new { area = "" }, new { @class = "navbar-brand" })
            </div>
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                <li>@Html.ActionLink("About application", "About", "Home")</li>
                <li>@Html.ActionLink("Vehicle Make", "Index", "Make")</li>
                <li>@Html.ActionLink("Vehicle Model", "Index", "Model")</li>
                <li>@Html.ActionLink("About author", "AboutAuthor", "Home")</li>
            </ul>
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                <li style="color: white; line-height: 50px;">
                <li>@Html.ActionLink("Login", "Login.aspx", "Login.aspx")</li>
                <li>@Html.ActionLink("Register", "Register.aspx", "Register.aspx")</li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="container body-content">
        @RenderBody()
        <hr />
        <footer>
            <p>&copy; @DateTime.Now.Year - Vehicle by Ivan Radunković</p>
        </footer>
    </div>

    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/bootstrap")
    @RenderSection("scripts", required: false)
</body>
</html>
```

My View/Shared/_Layout.cshtml

Comment: Please check [this article about asking questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) then edit your question by adding details/code. Also please do to put images instead of code/error text.

Comment: This has is all: https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Samples

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In shared/_Layout.cshtml you have to write code if user is loggedIn then display Name and Logg Off Text else show Login and Register Text(Button).

Like :

```
@if(Model.IsAuthenticated)
{
    <div>
      {Name(Fetch from model} Logg Off
    </div>
}
else
{
   <div> Register    Login
   </div>
}
```

Enjoy......

Comment: I am not shure where to put that code?

In my original post i edited and paste my _Layout.cshtml

Comment: 1st you have to add IsAuthenticated property in your model and set it accordingly in action method before calling view.

Answer (score 1):

If you can confirm that the users are being saved to the database then you just have to change your _Layout.cshtml:

```
@if(Model.IsAuthenticated)
{
    "Hello " + User.Identity.GetUserName()
}
else 
{
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <li style="color: white; line-height: 50px;">
        <li>@Html.ActionLink("Login", "Login.aspx", "Login.aspx")</li>
        <li>@Html.ActionLink("Register", "Register.aspx", "Register.aspx")</li>
    </ul>
}
```